# Weka SMO classifer keep returning one result

Tags: machine-learning, weka, svm, supervised-learning

I am using WEKA on my project. I use SVM(SMO) to classify the result. I firstly collected training set data and ran with 10fold crossvalidation. Then I built a classifier with those training set and made it ran in real-time, means real-time extracting features and passing them into the classifier. However, the classifier returns 0 at most cases( we have 5 labels, 0 is the first label)? It may return other label, but very rare.

What might be the possible reason that cause the classier keep outputting 0? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable reasons are:

- You trained such a trivial model, probably because you did not provide correct parameters for SVM for your particular dataset (which cannot be just "guessed", you need to find them)
- You have some kind of implementation error

nothing more can be told given such brief description of the problem.